# Saving undo-tree to restore in next session

Tags: undo-tree-mode

I wanted to know if `undo-tree` has a feature that saves the undo-tree of a file, and automatically restore it when opened in another session.
I went to the [undo-tree doc page](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/UndoTree), and of course the feature exists, it is called `undo-tree-auto-save-history`.

My questions are: How should I modify my init.el file in order to have the feature enabled for all kinds of files ? And is it going to auto-restore the undo-tree when opening a file ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Emacs is self-documenting in the sense that public variables functions and macros have documentation strings.

You get this string for `undo-tree-auto-save-history` by typing <kbd>C-h v</kbd> `undo-tree-auto-save-history` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

Your question

> And is it going to auto-restore the undo-tree when opening a file ?

is answered in the doc-string:

> When non-nil, `undo-tree-mode' will save undo history to file
>   when a buffer is saved to file.
>
> **It will automatically load undo history when a buffer is loaded
>   from file, if an undo save file exists.**
>
> By default, undo-tree history is saved to a file called
>   "..~undo-tree~" in the same directory as the
>   file itself. To save under a different directory, customize
>   `undo-tree-history-directory-alist' (see the documentation for
>   that variable for details).

Two possibilities to adjust that behavior:

1. Customize the variable `undo-tree-auto-save-history` with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-option` <kbd>RET</kbd> `undo-tree-auto-save-history` <kbd>RET</kbd>. Note that <kbd>TAB</kbd>-completion works.
2. Insert `(setq undo-tree-auto-save-history t)` in your init file.

Comment: Ok, the save works fine now :-), it just gives an error upon load (*Error reading undo-tree history from "/home/mraynal/Desktop/.test.py.~undo-tree~"*)